# responsive progress circle step bar

Tags: html, css, uikit

```css
.circle{
      padding:20px !important;
}
h2{
  margin:unset;
}
  .circle-text {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;

    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #FF9800 ;
    color: #fff;
    font: 18px "josefin sans", arial;
    line-height: 120px;


  }

.a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;  
}
.a:before,
.a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 60px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  top:0;
  width: 293px;

}
.a:before {
  right: 100%;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
.a:after {
  left: 100%;
  margin-left:0px;
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.25/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.25/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.25/css/uikit.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="uk-section-align  uk-margin-xlarge-top">
 <div class="uk-container">
   <div class="uk-text-center" uk-grid>
     <div class="uk-width-1-3 circle">
       <div class="circle-text ">
         <i class="medium material-icons">Step 1</i>
       </div>
       <p class="center-align  uk-margin-top">Choose Your Trip</p>
     </div>
     <div class="uk-width-1-3 ">
       <div class="circle-text a">
         <i class="medium material-icons">Step 2</i>
       </div>
       <p class="center-align uk-margin-top ">Request for reservation</p>
     </div>
     <div class="uk-width-1-3">
       <div class="circle-text ">
         <i class="medium material-icons">Step 3</i>
       </div>
       <p class="center-align  uk-margin-top">Successfully</p>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I want to make responsive progress bar using pure css and uikit 3. This code i was written it works when it show in desktop mode . when i switching desktop mode to mobile mode , middle black line strike both circle. i just want to when it show in mobile mode also it only touch the circle.
please give some suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```css
.circle{
      padding:20px !important;
}
h2{
  margin:unset;
}
  .circle-text {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;

    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #FF9800 ;
    color: #fff;
    font: 18px "josefin sans", arial;
    line-height: 120px;


  }

.a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;  
}

/* 
.a:before,
.a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 60px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  top:0;
  width: 293px;

}
.a:before {
  right: 100%;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
.a:after {
  left: 100%;
  margin-left:0px;
 
}
*/

.uk-process-step {
  position: relative;
}

.uk-process-step:before {
  top: 60px;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  content: " ";
  width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: black;
}
.uk-process-step .uk-width-1-3 {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.25/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.25/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.25/css/uikit.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="uk-section-align  uk-margin-xlarge-top">
 <div class="uk-container">
   <div class="uk-text-center uk-process-step" uk-grid>
     <div class="uk-width-1-3 circle">
       <div class="circle-text ">
         <i class="medium material-icons">Step 1</i>
       </div>
       <p class="center-align  uk-margin-top">Choose Your Trip</p>
     </div>
     <div class="uk-width-1-3 ">
       <div class="circle-text a">
         <i class="medium material-icons">Step 2</i>
       </div>
       <p class="center-align uk-margin-top ">Request for reservation</p>
     </div>
     <div class="uk-width-1-3">
       <div class="circle-text ">
         <i class="medium material-icons">Step 3</i>
       </div>
       <p class="center-align  uk-margin-top">Successfully</p>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank   u for your suggestion .it works. But I want to remove that extra black line whose  coming both side of circle .plz give some suggestion @PTA

Comment: .uk-process-step:before {
    top: 60px;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    content: " ";
    height: 5px;
    background-color: black;
    left: 15%;
    right: 15%;
}

Comment: Thank u for your suggestion and time . when i Put left :15% ; right:15%. it removed right side black line . but i want to remove both side those extra line came. please give some suggestion.  @PTA

Comment: Try remove "width: 100%;" in .uk-process-step:before

Comment: thank u for your suggestion. again i need your help . there is three circle  i want to change the color of  1st and 2nd circle. the line between 2nd and 3rd  circle
 will be dashed line . please help @ PTA

Comment: Thank you for your precious time . yeah half problem is solved but i want the line  between step 1 and step 2 is  normal straight  line  and when we complete our second step ,then line  between second and third line only be dashed line.i need half straight line and half dashed line . please give some suggestion @PTA

Comment: hey again i need your help @ PTA  when i changed to desktop mode to mobile mode .the circle is not responsive i used media query for that its not working . when i changed to mobile mode ,the circle become too big . i want to small  circle in mobile mode. . please give some suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Use z-index for the pseudo elements (the black line).

Set it to -1 so that it will go beyond the circle.

Try this

```css
.circle{
      padding:20px !important;
}
h2{
  margin:unset;
}
  .circle-text {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;

    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #FF9800 ;
    color: #fff;
    font: 18px "josefin sans", arial;
    line-height: 120px;


  }

.a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;  
}
.a:before,
.a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 60px;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  top:0;
  width: 293px;

}
.a:before {
  right: 100%;
  margin-right: 0px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.a:after {
  left: 100%;
  margin-left:0px;
  z-index:-1
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.25/js/uikit-icons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.25/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/3.0.0-rc.25/css/uikit.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="uk-section-align  uk-margin-xlarge-top">
 <div class="uk-container">
   <div class="uk-text-center" uk-grid>
     <div class="uk-width-1-3 circle">
       <div class="circle-text ">
         <i class="medium material-icons">Step 1</i>
       </div>
       <p class="center-align  uk-margin-top">Choose Your Trip</p>
     </div>
     <div class="uk-width-1-3 ">
       <div class="circle-text a">
         <i class="medium material-icons">Step 2</i>
       </div>
       <p class="center-align uk-margin-top ">Request for reservation</p>
     </div>
     <div class="uk-width-1-3">
       <div class="circle-text ">
         <i class="medium material-icons">Step 3</i>
       </div>
       <p class="center-align  uk-margin-top">Successfully</p>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank u for your suggestion.  there is three circle i want to change the color of 1st and 2nd circle. the line between 2nd and 3rd circle will be dashed line . please help @Viira